# Angular AOT & Rollup [!] Error: Unexpected token

Tags: angular, typescript, deployment, rollupjs, angular-compiler-cli

I'm following https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler tutorial, everything goes fine till rollup section.

When i run:

```
"node_modules/.bin/rollup"  -c rollup-config.js
```

I get those errors:

```
The following options have been renamed — please update your config: options.entry -> options.input, options.dest -> options.output.file, options.format -> options.output.format

src/main.ts → src/build.js...
The final argument to magicString.overwrite(...) should be an options object. See https://github.com/rich-harris/magic-string
[!] Error: Unexpected token
aot\src\app\app.module.ngfactory.ts (43:57)
41: import * as import32 from './all-holiday-requests/all-holiday-requests.component.ngfactory';
42: import * as import33 from '../../../src/app/app.component';
43: class AppModuleInjector extends import0.ɵNgModuleInjector<import1.AppModule> {
                                                             ^
44:   _NgProbeToken_2:any[];
45:   _ɵg_3:import2.ɵg;
```

Before that i was getting this:

```
The following options have been renamed — please update your config: options.entry -> options.input, options.dest -> options.output.file, options.format -> options.output.format

src/main.ts → src/build.js...
The final argument to magicString.overwrite(...) should be an options object. See https://github.com/rich-harris/magic-string
[!] Error: Could not resolve '../aot/src/app/app.module.ngfactory' from src\main.ts
Error: Could not resolve '../aot/src/app/app.module.ngfactory' from src\main.ts
    at error (D:\DEV\mdAutocomplete - test\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:185:14)
    at then.resolvedId (D:\DEV\mdAutocomplete - test\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:9776:8)
```

so i changed

```
main.ts

import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../aot/src/app/app.module.ngfactory';
```

to

```
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../aot/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts';
```

maybe that was a mistake. Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: You don't transpile your code.

Comment: What does that mean exacly?

Comment: That means that browsers often do not understand ES6+ or TypeScript. You need to somehow convert your code to something what they understand. It is ES5 JavaScript code.

Comment: There are special libraries for that. For example babel. Or tsc (for TypeScript). Or something else probably. You don't preprocess your code.

Comment: I don't know how to do this exactly in roll up. For example, in common you can just process your files to another directory and run your app on processed files. In webpack case you have loaders. For exaple babel-loader or ts-loader.

Comment: i think that `"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json` command should do that but i get a ton of errors when i run that command

Comment: even if i confugure `tsconfig-aot.json` like tutorial said